# Django admin site: Unable to lookup 'child model' on 'parent model or 'parent modelAdmin'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

This one's really difficult to write as a question since I'm not exactly sure how to ask this in the first place. But I'll try. Basically, I'm experiencing an AttributeError when I'm visiting the parent model in my django admin site. My current django database has 2 tables (except the prebuilt tables): a parent table / model for activity, and a child table / model for instruction. This is the structure of my models:

```
class activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

class instruction(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(activity,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__
```

So, if I add a new activity in the django admin site, say: Push-ups, then, I should be able to select this newly added parent record in the instruction form. However, when I try to add a new instruction record and select a saved activity record, the activity dropdown shows the name of the model only(in this case, activity). It doesn't show Push-ups. What I did next was to add some modelAdmins for the activity and instruction. Here's the code:

```
class activityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in activity._meta.get_fields()]

class instructionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in instruction._meta.get_fields()]

admin.site.register(activity, activityAdmin)
admin.site.register(instruction, instructionAdmin)
```

However, when I visit the activity page of the admin site this time, the page throws an AttributeError exception with the value `Unable to lookup 'instruction' on activity or activityAdmin`. This does not happen on the instruction page. I realized that this may not be the method to display the activity's title in the instruction form. Still, I need to add the modelAdmin in the admin.py in order to display all the fields of each models in the admin site. So in summary:

```
1. I need to display the parent model's field value (activity title) as an option in the child model's dropdown and not only the name of the parent model
2. I need to display the fields of each models on their respective registries in the admin site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your **str** definition. This is used as the dropdown display value and you are currently setting to the class name. If you want it to show the title in the dropdown:

```
class activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I see! That works. Do you have any idea how I can do the no #2?